# Help identifying pinout

Tags: camera, reverse-engineering, pinout

I've found a mini camera. The device has a mini-objective with a tag `P3.7` (I guess this is the resolution), 2 wires (red and white which I suppose are `Vin` and `Gnd`) and a pin connector.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to know what voltage is need without risk?
2. Does anyone know what the pinout and connector are?

I looked for a model number but there isn't one. Here the pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I dont have datasheet.

Comment: You don't have a datasheet, you don't have a model number and all we have are two images that look like they're upside down. I suspect you know more than we do, so it's difficult to see how anyone here can help.

Comment: I could add that this minicam could be from an ATM, but Im not sure.

Comment: I also tried googling numbers which appears in the circuit board... Nothing related to the device.

Comment: http://picpaste.com/P_20150430_152706_HDR-X2udZ1Ma.jpg

Comment: http://picpaste.com/P_20150430_152740_HDR-15rOmm8n.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chip marked 2360A.  This is a switching voltage regulator.

Check that the power connector goes to pin 6 of that chip.

Start out with a low voltage (2.5VDC) and go up.  The chip can handle up to 40VDC, so at some point well below that the regulator should start powering the camera.

Looks like [your camera is from a company named Pecan](http://www.smithstechnicalsystems.co.uk/pdf/cctv/Pecan_CCTV_Products_Brouchure.pdf) that link goes to a catalog.  Your module CS202 ([datasheet](http://www.sourcesecurity.com/datasheets/pecan-sm1286/co-1603-ga/SM1286.pdf)) seems to have a composite output.  Given the sticker on the back that says "PAL" and that I found the info on a site in the UK, I would expect the video signal to be for PAL TVs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of something that is just not worth the time to try to figure out. If you did somehow by chance get lucky and figure out the voltage requirements and the signal connector pinout you may very well get blocked at the next level. There may very well be some digital protocol on some signal pins that would take forever to reverse engineer.

I believe that you would be far far better off spending your time using a camera module that comes with a data sheet and that you can get some operational detail about. [Here is just one example](http://www.adafruit.com/product/397) that you can find online.

[image]

Comment: This is generally true, but an overly conservative approach. One should first try with the assumption that there's a simple composite video output, or a USB interface. These two cover 99% of all 4 pin interfaces on cameras. Another good thing to know is that almost every peripheral inside of a laptop made in the last 10 years is likely to be USB, too!